# How to use Vlookup inside VBA with a variable worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I need to use a vlookup inside vba but the worksheetname constantly changes but can always be referenced as ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(1) and ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(2). So I used dim so all selection can refer to ws1 and ws2 but of course inside a vlookup formula that kind of script doesn't work. Hope anyone can help rewrite those vlookup formula lines.

It regards the last 5 lines with the ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 lines where i need a solution for 'ws2'! 
Thanks for the help.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

ws1.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Web sales"
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Web stock"
Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Sales"
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Stock"
Range("F2:F71").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-102
Range("G2:J71").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("I5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("D3:D150").Select
ws2.Select
Range("D3:D150").Select
ws1.Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
Range("G3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'ws2'!RC[-3]:R[42]C[-1],3,0)"
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],ws2!R3C4:R45C6,3,0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are two examples from your original code showing how to include the name of worksheet into formula:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3]," & ws2.Name & "!RC[-3]:R[42]C[-1],3,0)"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3]," & ws2.Name & "!R3C4:R45C6,3,0)"
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, it would help people to add some more explanation or comments to your answer. Or at least point out what they did wrong.

Comment: @Jasper It is rather obvious in this case if someone read the question. The question was how to include the name of worksheet in the formula and I gave 2 examples based on the original code. What would you add to this?

Comment: Well, at least now I know it are two examples.

Comment: Thanks for the code Mielk but it does not completely work. The name of Worksheet 2 is Zenimax WEB week 30 so the formula should put it in the formula like 'Zenimax WEB week 30'! but it does this Zenimax WEB week '30'! so instead of the apostrophe before the Z it puts it before the 3. Any ideas how this is caused ?